# React child component state is lost after parent component re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am using a React hook for parent/child component.

Now I have state in my parent component (companyIcon), which I need to update based on some validation in the child component. I pass validationCallback as a callback function to the child component and update my parent state based on the value I get from the child.

Now the issue is after I update the parent state, the state value in my child component gets reset. What I am doing wrong in the below implementation ?

```
function ParentComp(props) {
    const [companyIcon, setCompanyIcon] = useState({ name: "icon", value: '' });

    const validationCallback = useCallback((tabId, hasError) => {
        if (hasError) {
            setCompanyIcon(prevItem => ({ ...prevItem, value: 'error'}));
// AFTER ABOVE LINE IS EXECUTED, my Child component state "myAddress" is lost i.e. it seems to reset back to empty value.
        }
    }, []);
    

    const MyChildCmp = (props) => { 
        const [myAddress, setmyAddress] = useState('');

        useEffect(() => {
                if (myAddressExceptions.length > 0) {
                    props.validationCallback('MyInfo', true);
                } else {
                    props.validationCallback('MyInfo', false);
                }
            }, [myAddressExceptions])

    
        const handlemyAddressChange = (event) => {        
            //setmyAddress(event.target.value);
            //setmyAddressExceptions(event.target.value);
            console.log(myAddressExceptions);
        }

        return (
            <>
                <div className="row" style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', width: '1000px'}}>
                        <div style={{ width: '20%'}}>
                            <FormField 
                                label='Company Address' 
                                required
                                helperText={mergedErrorMessages(myAddressExceptions)}
                                validationState={
                                    myAddressExceptions[0] ? myAddressExceptions[0].type : ''
                                }
                            >
                                <Input id='myAddress'
                                    value={myAddress}
                                    //onChange={handlemyAddressChange}
                                    onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                                        validateInputValue(value);
                                    }}
                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                    inputProps={{maxLength: 9}} />
                            </FormField>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </>
        ); 
    }

    return (
        <div className="mainBlock">
            Parent : {companyIcon}
            {displayMyChild && <MyChildCmp validationCallback={validationCallback}/>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(ParentComp);
```

Comment: Never define a child component inside a parent component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some reasons why you can lose state in child (there could be more, but these apply to you most):

```
    {displayMyChild && <MyChildCmp validationCallback={validationCallback}/>}
```

Here if at one point `displayMyChild` is truthy, then made `falsy`, this means the component `MyChildCmp` will get *unmounted*, hence all its state will be gone.

But now, even if you didn't have that condition and rendered the `MyChildCmp` always you would still run into similar problem, this is because you defined `MyChildCmp` *inside* another component. When you do that, on each render of the parent component, the function `MyChildCmp` is recreated, and the [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) algorithm of react thinks you rendered a *different component type* on next render, so it will destroy the component instance. Move definition of that component outside the parent component.